# Microsoft.CSharp' already has a dependency defined for 'NETStandard.Library'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

My Application is using .Net 4.5.2 framework. I am using Newtonsoft.Json of 10.0.1 version but While building the application i am getting below error :

**'Newtonsoft.Json' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.CSharp'.**

I have updated Microsoft.Csharp dll version from 4.0 to 4.5 in my project  and i am getting new error as below :

**Microsoft.CSharp' already has a dependency defined for 'NETStandard.Library'.** . Should i update the NETStandard.Library version. What should i do in this case to resolve this issue.

Comment: You need to update your project from 4.0 to 4.5. Right click on your project and go to properties.

Comment: @Icemanind : Thnx for your comment. I have updated the post.

Comment: These are the kind of errors you'd see if your project uses a .netstandard library.  Not the json library, something else.  The project's target framework version is much too low to allow this.  No big deal, targeting a framework version that has not been supported for a long time makes no sense.  .netstandard requires at least 4.6.1, 4.7.x is recommended.

Comment: @HansPassant : I have updated .Net version to 4.6.1 and now i am getting something new error   :   Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'System.Windows, Version=5.0.5.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' because it has not been preloaded. 
When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or 
loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event

Comment: Hi All... I have added manually System.Windows, Version=5.0.5.0 version and error gone but now i am getting error  as below  :                The property 'RenderingBias' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'